# vanilla Javascript, additional assignment operator misconception

Tags: javascript

as far as I understand, the additional assignment operator simply shortens the way we increment a value, e.g, instead of writing `x = x + 1` for instance, we use `x += 1`, Now, here is an example of a case that this approach didn't work for me as intended. I want to loop through a given string, add the current character to a predeclared empty object, if the character already exists in the object, i will increment its value by 1, if it does not, then I will add it with the value of 1. in other words I am building a character map of a given string.

```js
let charMap = {}

for (let char of 'doooppy') {
  charMap[char] = charMap[char] + 1 || 1;
}
```

this works like a charm. now check the following

```js
let charMap = {} 

for (let char of 'doooppy') {
  charMap[char] += 1 || 1;
}
```

this now returns a NaN, which is pretty weird to me as its the same idea of using the assignment operator. can somebody explain why is that ?! thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1 || 1` is being evaluated before `charMap[char] += 1 || 1;` is evaluated. That's the way operator precedence in JavaScript works. The part with || is evaluated before the part with +=. The first time that line of code is run, charMap[char] is undefined. Using += on undefined returns NaN, and then in subsequent executions using += on NaN also returns NaN.

Correct solution with += would be:

```js
let charMap = {} 

for (let char of 'doooppy') {
  if (!charMap[char]) {
    charMap[char] = 1;
  } else {
    charMap[char] += 1;
  }
}
```